# KeyError when trying to apply function

Tags: python

I get an exception when I try to run the following line:

```
totalBarrios['barrio'] = totalBarrios['barrio'].apply(name_fct)
```

I obtained totalBarrios like this:

```
totalBarrios = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby(['barrio'])['n_personas'].sum());
totalBarrios
```

[image]

Here's my function name_fct

```
def name_fct (df):
    if df in ["NuÃ±ez", "NUÑEZ"]:
        new_df = "NUÑEZ"
        return new_df
    else:
        return df.upper()
```

### Full Traceback:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
 
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
 
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
 
KeyError: 'barrio'
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
 
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
 
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
 
KeyError: 'barrio'
```

Comment: What's the value of `totalBarrios`?

Comment: The problem is that after defining the new dataframe from the groupby object, `'barrio'` is the index column and not a normal column that you address via its name. Use `totalBarrios.index` instead.

Comment: @DavidWierichs Is there a way to make barrio a normal column? So that I can access it via its name.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].** Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to fix it:

```
totalBarrios = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby(['barrio'], as_index=False)['n_personas'].sum());
```

I added `'as_index=False'`.

Answer (score 0):

If `totalBarrios` is a dictionary, that error means that there is no key named `'barrio'` in your `totalBarrios` dictionary.

Comment: so how do I make barrio a key?

Comment: Can I see your `dict`?